# datetime.now() gets different time than the one my pc has configured

Tags: python

I've been looking through this sites posts on this issue i have, and none of them solve my problem so far. What happens is that my `datetime.now()` method from `datetime` module doesnt show time as configured in my pc, so here i did some tests in order to figure out what's happening. a few minutes ago I solved it by specifying the timezone through `dateutil` module, but it shouldn't be done in that way.

Note: I'm currently using Ubuntu/Linux OS, and use a virtual environment for my project.

**CODE:**

```
from dateutil import tz
from datetime import date, datetime, time

date1 = datetime.now(tz.tzlocal()) # it works not at all
date1_ = datetime.now() # Same thing
date2 = datetime.now(tz.gettz('Cuba')) # it does now
date1_tz_info = date1.timetz()
print(date1, date1_, date2, sep='\n')
print(date1_tz_info)
```

**OUTPUT:**

1. 2021-01-19 22:39:13.960834+00:00
2. 2021-01-19 22:39:13.960874
3. 2021-01-19 17:39:13.961087-05:00 #The Right Output
4. 22:39:13.960834+00:00

[Picture from pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k48yz.png)

So as far as seen now datetime.now() returns value as if it was utc +00:00.

Comment: What does `import time; time.tzname` say?

Comment: Code looks good to me and it should work per your expectation.

Comment: @mhawke , i got "('UTC', 'UTC')" printed

Comment: @Panchdev, yes but for some reason it shows time in UTC format disregarding  the timezone i have configured or any ...

Comment: @L0neW0lf: there's your answer. Your Python interpreter thinks the timezone is UTC which is why you get those results. Are there any timezone settings in your shell that might override the system tz? Try `import os; print(os.environ['TZ'])`. Check your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` files, or just try `echo $TZ` in your shell.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x, local timezone can be figured out like this:

```
import datetime
LOCAL_TIMEZONE = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).astimezone().tzinfo
```

if the python version is before 3.6 you can use

```
import datetime
LOCAL_TIMEZONE = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(0))).astimezone().tzinfo
```

From that we can see which timezone python thinks is local.  How to change the time zones for windows 10 is below

In windows command prompt try:

This gives current timezone:

> tzutil /g

This gives a list of timezones:

> tzutil /l

This will set the timezone:

> tzutil /s "Central America Standard Time"

For further reference: http://woshub.com/how-to-set-timezone-from-command-prompt-in-windows/

Comment: UTC is the result, i use python 3.8

Comment: I don't want timezone, I want the system time

Answer (score -1):

After over 2 hours of research i came across an answer.

A few points to be told before getting to it:

1. it turns out that the problem had to do with the virtual environment that i have set, (it wasn't able to use variables exported from .bashrc file (for some reason the TZ var i exported from .bashrc doesnt exist in my virtualenv), so this approach from start in the end didnt work).
2. So... i thought on exporting them via a file on /etc/profile.d/ path, so it could be seen across all shells for all users.
3. Then... after losing some of my hair trying to figure out what on earth was happening, it resulted that virtualenv direnv was creating/deleting/modifying variables according to the path i was at.

Finally, what i did is to add export TZ='America/Havana' in .envrc file which is located at one's project root folder, allowed it from direnv program then reloaded, afterwards i typed the following to check my solution.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['TZ']
'America/Havana'
>>> import datetime
>>> print(datetime.datetime.now())
2021-01-20 00:21:00.189968
>>> print(datetime.datetime.now().astimezone())
2021-01-20 00:21:16.195877-05:00
>>>
```

As you can appreciate, finally... at last.. the time zone difference between UTC (00:00) and mine is taken into account for unaware datetime objects.

Note: I am a rookie regarding to Python and Linux operating systems, so if some of my words lack of fundament, please don't mind it.